# Trying to find out why this WordPress short code generates and error when put in a page

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, phpexcel

Attached is code that reads an excel file and returns a value to be used in a page through a WordPress short code.  The code comes from here http://metinerbek.com/article/get-data-from-excel-with-php

```
<?php 
add_shortcode( 'tpmcme', function ($attr) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
            'course' => 'A',
        ), $attr );
    require("reader.php"); 
    $file="TPM.xls";
    $connection=new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(); 
    $connection->read($file);
    if ($args['course'] == 'AM1') {
        $startrow=6;
        $endrow=7;
        $col1=10;
        for($i=$startrow;$i<$endrow;$i++){  
            $value = $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$col1]; 
            return $value;
        } 
    } else if ($args['course'] == 'ANAdvanced') {
        $startrow=12;
        $endrow=13;
        $col1=10;
        for($i=$startrow;$i<$endrow;$i++){ 
            $value = $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$col1]; 
            return $value;
        } 
    } else if ($args['course'] == 'ANBasic') {
        $startrow=14;
        $endrow=15;
        $col1=10;
        for($i=$startrow;$i<$endrow;$i++){ 
            $value = $connection->sheets[0]["cells"][$i][$col1]; 
            return $value;
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Now here is the problem.  The code works just as intended but when I insert the short code into a page with an argument and save the page it will then say that a critical error has occurred.  I can use my browser’s back button and go back to the page and everything will be fine.

A couple of things of note.
1 – the version of WordPress I am using is current and up to date.
2 – the version of PHP I am using is current and up to date.
3 – I am using the code snippets plugin to store the code.
4 – I did get the following error sent to me :     An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 6 of the file /nas/content/live/tpm20/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446) : eval()'d code. Error message: require(): Failed opening required 'reader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/php:/usr/share/php')

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: In which path reader.php file located?

Comment: Its in the main WordPress folder.

Comment: can you share the both dir of reader.php and shortcode file located?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: reader.php must be in the same dir path where your shortcode code is.

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you for your help!